# How to retrieve the text of a hidden element using selenium

Tags: selenium

Here we know the Birimingam value. Based out of that value need to retrieve the  text "BHM". Have indicated this in the image. How to retrieve hidden text which is "BHM" using Birimingham value xpath?

[image: Click here to view the image described]

Comment: Provide the HTML source for this element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath to access the element

`//span[text()='Birmingham']/../../preceding-sibling::span/span`

Comment: It Worked .. Thank you.. Could you please share any source to learn parent sibling xpaths in better way